# LocalStorage in Contact Manager (knockoutjs)

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

This app is a Contact Manager. And I want when user is filling the form and click save the contacts which appears to be stored in local storage so I could remove some of them etc. Adding and removing are working but it's not storing.

Here is the app:
http://jsfiddle.net/vpbj32Lh/

The problem in this lines:

```
self.load = function(){
    self.contacts = localStorage.getItem("stored_contacts");
}

self.save = function(){

    localStorage.setItem("stored_contacts", self.contacts); 
    self.contacts=localStorage.getItem("stored_contacts");

    console.log(self.contacts.length);
}
```

If you delete this lines and "data-bind="click: save" in html file. It willbe adding and removing but not saving and loading

Comment: What does that mean 'it's not storing'?

Comment: @PWKad It's not saving or loading contacts after refreshing the page

Comment: localStorage is pretty straightforward to use. Did you debug it with dev tools and make sure each function is being called? I would also check that you're not trying to store too much data. Local storage has a data size limit that is different with each browser.

Comment: @jlafay I know about data size limit. Yeah, I've tried to solve this but as you can see I couldn't

Comment: @ovesyan19, I don't see any signs of trying to solve it. What happened when you debugged the save and load functions?

Comment: @jlafay It showed me length of function. If I write self.contacts() it tells that string is not a function. Many variants I tried

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint inside the functions so you can see them executing when you expect them to load and save. You can also see what is inside of the localStorage as each line of code executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a number of things to change in your code.
This is a fixed version:

**JS**

```
(function ContactManager(){
  // ...

  self.contacts = ko.observableArray();

  self.addItem = function(){
    self.contacts.push(new Contact(self.conName(), self.phone(), self.email(), self.address()));
  }
  // ...
  self.load = function(){
    // haven't tested, but probably won't work. I think you'd have to convert your JSON to observables
    self.contacts = localStorage.getItem("stored_contacts"); 
  }

  self.save = function(){
    self.addItem(); // calling it from here, not from your HTML form submit
    // you have to convert to JSON to save in localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("stored_contacts", ko.toJSON(self.contacts()));
  }

  ko.applyBindings(self.templateName);
})();
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="addContact" autocomplete="on"> 
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

A couple of observations:

`self.contacts = ko.observableArray(self.save);` - this doesn't make any sense. You are initializing an observableArray with a function object. You are not even calling the function, you are passing the function. Either way, doesn't make sense here.

`<form data-bind="submit: addItem" >` and `<button data-bind="click: save" type="submit">` - you are binding an event to your click on the button, and another event to the submit of the form, that happens when... well, when you click on the button. This maybe would work with some setup, but wasn't working, so I called the `addItem` from the `save`.

`localStorage.setItem("stored_contacts", self.contacts);` - you are trying to store an array of very complex objects (the contacts), each one full of several other complex objects (the observables) inside localStorage. localStorage, though, *only stores strings*. So you have to convert your objects to JSON. `ko.toJSON` is the way to go. More at the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html).

**Edit:**

[This is a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vpbj32Lh/1/) with the saving part. I don't know how does JSFiddle handles the localStorage, but as I told you in the comments on my code in the original answer, your `load` function is wrong and will have to read the string from the localStorage, parse it to JSON (with `JSON.parse(string)`) and construct the appropriate objects using your constructor function (`Contact`). This is pretty easy and you can do by yourself.

**Edit 2:**

The load function should be something like this (haven't tested):

```
  self.load = function(){
    var contactsJSON = localStorage.getItem("stored_contacts"); // a string
    var loadedContacts = JSON.parse(contactsJSON); // an array
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray(); // an observableArray
    for (var i in loadedContacts) {
      var loadedContact = loadedContacts[i]; // an object
      var newContact = new Contact(/* pass the parameters from loadedContact*/); // a Contact object
      self.contacts.push(newContact);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's pretty much it. And thanks for explanation, I appreciate it!

Comment: Now I stuck in the load function. Can you show me the answer so I can understand finally how to do things with localStorage, cause I often have problems with it @rafaeleyng

Comment: @ovesyan19 See Edit 2

Comment: so where to call "load" function? @rafaeleyng

Comment: That is up to you, I think. When do you want to load your contacts from localStorage? At the application startup?

Comment: Yeah, I want saved contacts to be loaded at the start @rafaeleyng

Comment: Well, then you must run it when your ViewModel (`ContactManager`) is instatiated. Like before `ko.applyBindings(self.templateName);` you could call `self.load()`

Comment: Yous said "pass the parameters from loadedContact". So what parameters does loadedContact have? I don't understand what's going on in the last two lines @rafaeleyng

Comment: The last two lines are: you have a object that has the same properties that a Contact object (conName, phone, email, address), but it is not a Contact object (its properties aren't the observables). So you use the loadedContact to build the new Contact object. `var newContact = new Contact(loadedContact.conName, loadedContact.phone, loadedContact.email, loadedContact.address);`. The last line, you are putting your `newContact` in the array of contacts that will be displayed.

Comment: I've mistaken, actually this line "var newContact=..." I didn't get. Now it's all clear, thank you for the explanation again! @rafaeleyng

Comment: Have you got skype or fb where I can ask you a few more questions if you're not to busy? @rafaeleyng

Comment: If you have more questions, I suggest you to post it to the community answer it.

Comment: Ok, I will ,but I forgot to ask about removing elements. It's loading what I saved but when I delete contact and refresh the page it's not deleting it. How can I fix that with localStorage? @rafaeleyng

Comment: I thought "localStorage.removeItem()" will do my thing. It actually did, but removed all contacts, not the one I was removing. I don't know what to pass between brackets, actually what to do to trigger that one contact which I want to delete @rafaeleyng

Comment: localStorage is a key-value storage. You are storing all of your contacts under the same key, `"stored_contacts"`. If you want to remove each one separately, you should store each one separately.

Comment: But that requires you to change all of your functions. But that's far beyond the scope of this question. So, if you need some more help, post another question and wait for someone else answer. I won't be answering your questions *add infinitum* in this comments.